# "Standard cars in the US" or "the standard cars in the US"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if I need to use *the* before *standard* in the following context?

> Standard cars in the US are pretty good.
>
> **The** standard cars in the US are pretty good.

What I'm trying to say is that (the) regular cars in the US are pretty good, not some specific cars.

Comment: standard cars is for a general statement. "the" is not needed. Apples are good for you.

Comment: While I assume you were just using cars as an example noun, the word 'standard' has an extra meaning for cars: automatic transmission versus manual (standard) transmission.  You may want to clarify the question to exclude that from consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "the", you are referring to something you have mentioned, or that the reader will recognize as existing.
If you are creating a new category, "standard cars", meaning cars that aren't special or distinguished from other cars, then it's better to omit the word "the".

Here's an example using an article:
Cars are made in two colors, black and white. **The** black cars go faster at night, and **the** white cars go faster in the daytime.

Here's an example without an article:
White cars don't show dust as much as black cars, but they show mud more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What about the fact that I am talking about cars in a specific country like in my example? Is "the" still not necessary?

Comment: You are using "standard" a a way of distinguishing some cars from others, so a further specifier "the" may not be necessary. It's hard to give a definitive answer without seeing the text that the word occurs in. There may be some texts where "the" is optional.